# Spring MVC and sql (Oracle) stored procedure

Tags: database, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I have one stored procedure.
Name :

```
 valid_user(p_user_nm,p_pwd,p_user_typ,p_p_userip,p_browser,p_browser_ver,.......)
```

and some OUT parameter.
Now I want to login using Username and Password.
How I do it?
I use Ajax, Spring MVC, and jdbctemplate.

How to call stored procedure using jdbctemplate in spring MVC?

Comment: There's an example at https://github.com/Spring-mvc-example/spring-mvc-stored-procedure-call

Comment: But I want the connection using jdbctemplate

Comment: Try Google.  You'll find this:  http://www.luv2code.com/2011/11/10/calling-stored-procedures-with-spring-jdbc-templates/

Comment: It helps me a lot